# Is there a linear operator $T$ such that $T(x^n) =f(n)x^{n-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, operator-theory

When I first learnt calculus I was so surprised to learn that there is a meaningful mathematical operator $D$ that
$$
D(x^n)= n x^{n-1}.
$$
It seems to be a very random thing to multiply the exponent by the function and subtract one from the exponent to get the correct result.
Again, this sounded very strange for me when I first learnt about derivatives, I mean if I was asked before I learnt the calculus of $D$ I would have dismissed this as a random useless property. Back then I thought about this question: is there a mathematical operator $T$ such that
$$
T(x^n) =f(n)x^{n-1}\;?
$$
After $6$ years now I remembered the question and I modified it as follows: can a linear operator $T$ defined on the vector space of all vector space of all polynomials and power series be such that
$$
T(x^n) =f(n)x^{n-1}\quad \ n \ne 0 
$$ for any continuous $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and can this operator be represented via known linear operator(s) (derivatives, integrals, etc. ), and known functions and $f$ ?

After some thought I think the answer is no. Even a simple function like $f(x)=c\ne 0$ is very  hard to find and I couldn't find such representation.

Comment: The answer to the question depends on what domain/range you want for your operator.

Comment: General idea: Arbitrary values can be assingned on a linearly independent set for a linear map.

Comment: A linear operator is a linear transformation from a vector space to itself. What is your vector space here? The vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients? Of all functions from the reals to the reals? Of all differentiable functions from the reals to the reals?

Comment: If your vector space is such that the powers of $x$ are linearly independent, then you can just decide where $x^n$ is mapped for each $n$ (including something of the form $f(n)x^{n-1}$); assuming the Axiom of Choice, just extend the powers of $x$ to a basis, and you can define a linear transformation by deciding the value at the vectors of the basis and extending linearly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It is the vector of all  vector space of all polynomials.

Comment: Then yes, you can *define* a linear transformation simply by specifying its value at all $x^n$ and extending linearly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin if I am interpreting the question correctly, I believe that the goal is to find a “closed form representation” of $T_f(x^n) = f(n)x^{n-1}$ when given a function $f$

Comment: @WhileIAm Which would be $T_f(a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n) = f(1)a_1 + f(2)a_2x + \cdots + f(n)a_nx^{n-1}$. This will be a linear function. And?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The question is : give a closed form via known operators like $D$ 

lets assume that $T(x^n) = D^{(2)}(x^n)- D^{(-1)}(x^n)$ then $T = D^{(2)}- D^{(-1)} $ is the answer

Answer (score 7):

It might depend on the function $f$ to be considered ultimately, but it is actually quite easy to construct such a linear operator $T$ when $f$ can be expanded into some power series (like Taylor series), i.e. $f(t) = \sum_k a_kt^k$. Indeed, since $(xD)x^n = nx^n$ (meaning that $x^n$ is the eigenfunction of $xD$ associated to the eigenvalue $n$), one has $f(xD)x^n = f(n)x^n$, hence formally
$$
T_f = x^{-1}f(xD) = x^{-1} \sum_k a_k(xD)^k.
$$
For example with $f = \exp$ :
$$
T_{\exp}(x^n) = x^{-1}e^{xD}x^n = x^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(xD)^k}{k!} x^n = x^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} x^n = e^nx^{n-1}
$$
It is to be noted that the above power expansion may also contain negative powers (cf. Laurent series). In that case, the inverse operator $(xD)^{-1} = D^{-1}x^{-1}$ has to be understood as
$$
(xD)^{-1}\phi(x) = \int \frac{\phi(x)}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
hence for instance with $f(t) = 1/t$ :
$$
T_f(x^n) = x^{-1}(xD)^{-1}x^n = x^{-1} \int \frac{x^n}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x = x^{-1} \int x^{n-1} \,\mathrm{d}x = x^{-1} \frac{x^n}{n} = \frac{1}{n}x^{n-1}
$$